# The request signature does not match when access aws-api-gateway on Retrofit

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, retrofit, aws-api-gateway

I have used the okhttp-aws-signer library to sign aws requests and pass it using Retrofit 2 on Android. I also ask about this problem on the lib repository 
https://github.com/babbel/okhttp-aws-signer/issues/1

I have got an error every time to make Retrofit API call. Secret and access keys are good because it works with Postman. Library is in Kotlin, and my app is in Java, but I think it does not matter, right? Can you tell what is wrong?

```
public class AwsSigingHeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor 

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {


Request request = chain.request();
Request newrequest = request.newBuilder()
        .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
        .addHeader("Method", "POST")
        .addHeader("Host", request.url().host())
        .addHeader("X-Amz-Date", DateUtil.getAwsDate())
        .addHeader("Accept", Constants.ACCEPT)
        .addHeader("Content-Type", Constants.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON).build();


OkHttpAwsV4Signer okHttpAwsV4Signer = new OkHttpAwsV4Signer(Constants.REGION, Constants.SERVICE_NAME);

newrequest = okHttpAwsV4Signer.sign(newrequest, Constants.ACCESS_KEY_ID, Constants.ACCESS_SECRET_KEY);


return chain.proceed(newrequest);
}

}
```

This is packed header Authorization key, packed with mentioned signer for aws.

```
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAIR5PPPODHO6F2NCA/20190207/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;cache-control;content-type;host;method;x-amz-date, Signature=5521d5b220cb427ddbcbad5f9bda6bd69043c779e67999d3ee92957e45112479
```

This is an error which I got, I should got some JSON object.

> {"message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details...

Comment: Solved. Just remove these header options: 
.addHeader("Method", "POST")
.addHeader("Accept", Constants.ACCEPT)
.addHeader("Content-Type", Constants.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON)